# How do I generate a duplicate index based on duplicate values in a different column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing

#### starting data

I want to generate an incrementing index that takes in consideration duplicates in the ['name'] column.

```
name
vendor1
vendor2
vendor2
vendor3
vendor4
vendor4
vendor4
vendor4
```

#### desired output

```
id    name
1     vendor1
2     vendor2
2     vendor2
3     vendor3
4     vendor4
4     vendor4
4     vendor4
4     vendor4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) of column `name` and assign to index:

```
df.index = pd.factorize(df['name'])[0] + 1
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much @jezrael !